# persistent volume claim is unable to mount on the pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pvc

I have setup a GKE cluster anad enabled the `FileStore CSI driver`. I have created the below `StorageClass`, `PersistentVolumeClaim` and the `Deployment` configuration

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: filestore-sc
provisioner: filestore.csi.storage.gke.io
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
allowVolumeExpansion: true
parameters:
  tier: standard
  network: default
```

`kubectl apply -f <storage-class>.yaml`

`filestore-sc  filestore.csi.storage.gke.io  Delete  Immediate  true 17m`

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: fileserver
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: filestore-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Ti
```

`kubectl apply -f <pvc.yaml>`

`NAME         STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS        AGE fileserver   Bound    pvc-214e64b5-a28c-4d30-9e23-ba08fbed1482   1Ti        RWX            filestore-sc        17m`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: reader
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: reader
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: reader
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: fileserver
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html # the shared directory 
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: fileserver
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: fileserver
```

`kubectl get pods`
`NAME           READY   STATUS       RESTARTS   AGE reader-5c9cf696f-clgkm   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          15m`

`kubectl describe po reader-5c9cf696f-clgkm`

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                From               Message
  ----     ------       ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    16m                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/reader-5c9cf696f-clgkm to gke-primary-general-effdaa23-xqqt
  Warning  FailedMount  13m (x6 over 14m)  kubelet            MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-214e64b5-a28c-4d30-9e23-ba08fbed1482" : rpc error: code = Aborted desc = An operation with the given volume key modeInstance/us-central1-a/pvc-214e64b5-a28c-4d30-9e23-ba08fbed1482/vol1 already exists.
 --- Most likely a long process is still running to completion. Retrying.
  Warning  FailedMount  34s (x7 over 14m)  kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[fileserver], unattached volumes=[], failed to process volumes=[]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  2s (x5 over 14m)   kubelet  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-214e64b5-a28c-4d30-9e23-ba08fbed1482" : rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
```

Where am I going wrong? I am following this guide [Link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/stateful-workload#new-instance)